# R Selecting a Row plus the next 5 rows

Tags: r

In my dataframe I would like to select a row based on some logic, and then return a dataframe with the selected row PLUS the next 'N' rows.

So, I have this: (a generic example)

```
workingRows <- myData[which(myData$Column1 >= myData$Column2 & myData$Column3 <= myData$Column4), ]
```

Which returns me the correct "starting values". How can I get the "next" 5 values based on each of the starting values?

Comment: For next time: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Ok, I got it, next time I'll give a minimal dataset for people to test against.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `rep` to get the next 5 rows, `sort` it and if there are any duplicates from overlaps, wrap it with `unique` and subset the 'myData'.

```
i1 <-  which(myData$Column1 >= myData$Column2 & myData$Column3 <= myData$Column4)
myData[unique(sort(i1 + rep(0:5, each = length(i1)))),]
```

Comment: Oh, good, I was just about to suggest adding unique, but you saw the potential for overlaps.